# Como fazer um grafico apartir de um dicionario python

Tags: sql, python, sqlite, graphics

estou querendo fazer um gráfico em python puxando informações de um dicionário.

No meu caso é o seguinte, eu tenho uma data inicial e final, eu fiz a diferença entre as duas.

Caso a diferença seja igual a 0 e 1 irá adicionar na chave de 2018.

Se a diferença for igual a 2 irá adicionar na chave de 2018 e 2019 e assim por diante.

E no final de tudo quero que ele mostre quantos valores tem em cada chave dentro do gráfico.

seguem me código abaixo:

```
def show_graphic(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.sql = "SELECT * FROM inventory WHERE modality = ?"
    self.sql = "SELECT * FROM inventory WHERE process_start = ?"
    self.result_1 = c.execute(self.sql,(self.modality_r.get(),))
    #TODO: fazer o grafico apartir de um dicionario.
    self.vali = {2018:[0],
                 2019:[0],
                 2020:[0],
                 2021:[0],
                 2020:[0],
                 2021:[0],
                 2022:[0],
                 2023:[0],
                 2024:[0],
                 2025:[0],
                 2026:[0],
                 2027:[0],
                 2028:[0],
                 2029:[0],
                 2030:[0]}

    for row in (self.result_1):
        self.moda1 = row[1]
        self.date1 = row[3]
        self.date2 = row[4]

        self.date1 = datetime.strptime(self.date1,'%d/%m/%Y').date()
        self.date2 = datetime.strptime(self.date2,'%d/%m/%Y').date()

        if self.date1.year >= 2018 :
            self.minus = abs((self.date1 - self.date2).days)
            self.month = self.minus // 30
            self.year = self.month // 12






    plt.plot(self.vali.keys(), self.vali.values())
    plt.xticks(self.vali.keys())
    plt.yticks(self.vali.values())

    plt.ylabel('Total  de pessoas')
    plt.xlabel('Ano')
    plt.grid(True)
    plt.show()
```

Aqui tem uma imagem do meu banco de dados, estou pegando as informações dele lá:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Não entendi direito como funciona o seu dicionário. O que está sendo adicionado nele é uma data? A diferença das datas? Um incremento de +1 para contar as ocorrências? No código não mostra como o dicionário é atualizado. E o gráfico esperado é um histograma? Poderia deixar isto mais claro na pergunta por favor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Com o matplotlib é tranquilo de fazer.

`import matplotlib.pyplot as plt`

Se o seu dicionário for um contador de ocorrências, é só fazer

```
dicionario = {2018:30, 2019:28, [...] ,2024:3}

plt.bar(dicionario.keys(), dicionario.values())
plt.show()
```

Se ele for uma lista de eventos, podemos usar list comprehension e ver quantos eventos tem em cada lista:

```
dicionario = {2018:[1, 2,[...], 90],
              2019:[3, 24,[...], 39],
              [...]
              2024:[10, 20,[...], 54]}

plt.bar(dicionario.keys(), [len(x) for x in dicionario.values()])
plt.show()
```

Ou ainda somar os valores dentro dele:

```
plt.bar(dicionario.keys(), [sum(x) for x in dicionario.values()])
plt.show()
```

Comment: Obrigado, acabei que demorei para ver e acabei descobrindo sozinho!